# Errno 13 Permission denied when streaming live tweets with tweepy

Tags: python, json, twitter, listener, tweepy

I am new to python as well as streaming tweets. I use Anaconda distribution:

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I followed an [online tutorial](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/02/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-1/) to get started. I was able to successfully set up my developer profile and download some tweets with tweepy 3.5.0.

Then I tried implementing the streaming code from the article:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

class MyListener(StreamListener):


def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        with open('python2.json', 'a') as f:
            f.write(data)
            return True
    except BaseException as e:
        #print(&quot;Error on_data: %s&quot; % str(e))
        print 'error', str(e)
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)
    return True

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=['#SuperBowl'])
```

At first **everything works fine** and:
 - python2.json is created in the working directory
 - I am getting my live tweets ([I track the number of lines in the json output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLm7e.png), the number of lines increases)

**I start getting these [Errno 13] errors** when:
 - the number of lines is about 650 
 - file size gets to about 4000 KB
 - rate at which I receive tweets slows down, but doesn't stop completely

```
execfile('twitter_api_streaming.py')
error [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'python2.json'
error [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'python2.json'
error [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'python2.json'
```

**So my question is:** what exactly does this error mean for my script? Does it have to do with the size of my json file? Will it eventually break my script?

Thanks so much!

Comment: 13 is `EACCESS`, which means you don't have permission to the file. The file size shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: hey @Barmar, but how can it be if I am still writing into the file? The number of lines keeps growing while I am getting this error multiple times.

Comment: I don't know, but the error message says it right there: "Permission denied".